# Запуск React приложение на удаленном сервере

Tags: node.js, reactjs, сервер

Написал приложение на monbgoDB + nodejs + react. Все на локалхосте работает. Купил на ruvds сервер, залил туда все с репозитория и сделал npm install у сервера и у фронта (они в разных папках). Сервер работает прекрасно, спокойно обращаюсь к нему по :port. Реакт тоже компилиться и ошибок не выдает, но из сети его не видно, если по такому же адресу зайти :port(порт естественно я ввожу тот, на котором запускается реакт) Подскажите как развернуть это дело, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что `:port` не 80й. А, браузер по умолчанию работает именно с ним.

Здесь либо переделывать проект под 80й порт, либо пробрасывать 80й порт на Ваш `:port` через какой-нибудь nginx.

Comment: Я обращаюсь по адресу с указанием порта, через браузер, он 8080 и я обращаюсь к нему

Comment: А, 8080 на сервере открыт?.

Comment: А я не знаю, есть способ узнать?

Comment: Смотрите настройки файрвола.